# PHPMailer don't work get_include_contents functions on called php fie

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer in my project.

First, we created the mail-customer.php file we prepared, and then we called this file through the phpmailer function mail-sender.php

*PHP code in mail-customer.php does not work or we do not know how to call variables.*

Can you help me with this and can you give me a detailed explanation? Thank you from now.
The code for **mail-customer.php** is as follows.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body style="font-size:14px;background: #e1e1e1;">
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Dear $name
<?php echo $name;?>  <p>Thank you for contact</p>Best regards</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

The code for **mail-sender.php**

```
$data['name']    = $_POST['name'];
$data['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];

    function get_include_contents($file_name, $local_variables) {

        extract($local_variables);
        if (is_file($file_name)) {
            ob_start();
            include $file_name;
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Called function in **mail-sender.php** file is as follows

```
$mail1->msgHTML(get_include_contents('mail-customer.php'), $data);
```

Comment: You need to check what's coming back from your `get_include_contents` function; don't just assume it works, as you are currently. You're getting close votes because you have not provided a clear problem statement - you're not saying what *is* happening, only that it's not what you expect.